# Optimize app launch time on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Right now i am confused with my app launch time.

I am developing app it uses about 10 ViewControllers - most os them have only TableViews that are filled from JSON server response. All responses are made in  dispatch_async calls.

I use MMDrawerController, SwiftLoader, OneSignal Framework, SwiftyJSON and few small libraries. I added Core Data to app - so that some data is cached there but it didn't make launch time shorter.

I also use some images (most of them are icons - other few - background images) - total size of images used in interface of all views is about 6 mb.

The problem is that my app is loading to slow. It take about 10 seconds to load first ViewController on iPhone 5.

I tried to use allocations profiling instrument. Do you see any problems here?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to load all of this stuff in AppDelegate? If so, which function within the class are you doing it?

Comment: Yes, what are you doing on your app launch? Check in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Are you trying to initiate web services? Also take a look at your main view controller. Are you trying to build an intense UI or creating a bunch of objects in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of AppDelegate i only initialize OneSignal push service and MMDrawerController. Functions to load data from server are placed in viewDidLoad

Comment: From the Instruments capture it seems that you are doing too much work in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - Can you show this code?  If you need to fetch network data for the cell you should either pre-fetch or put some placeholder content in the cell while you load the content in the background.

Comment: My cell have about 6 UI items - most of them are labels, all data is loaded from array of items that were loaded from JSON. My loading time is not good enough in this case?